# Relative clause with "which kind"

Tags: relative-clauses

Consider this sentence:

> I don't know which kind of filtering they used that can't even be opened by a proxy!

or

> I don't know which kind of filtering they used that even it can't be opened by a proxy!

What is the structure of such sentences? "Which kind of .... that ... even ...."

For another example consider:

> I don't know which technology they used in this mobile set that even works under water.

Is it a correct sentence. If yes what is the structure of it? Is it a relative clause?

Answer (score 1):

You ask:

> What is the structure of such sentences? "Which kind of .... that ...
>   even ...."

The pattern to which you're referring is, I suspect, a rhetorical statement whose tone is  sarcastic, and the irony is expressed by the speaker's feigning ignorance.

> **I don't know** what's so "advanced" about the camera, when it doesn't even
>   have a low-light setting.
>
> **I don't know** what's so "advanced" about a camera that doesn't even
>   have a low-light setting.
>
> **Beats me** what's so "advanced" about a camera that doesn't even have a low-light setting.

The speaker here portrays himself or herself as someone who lacks the knowledge or brains to say why the camera can be called "advanced"; his or her limited sense of how things ought to be would require an "advanced" camera to have a low-light setting. The speaker is at a loss to say why it's "advanced".  Of course the actual meaning is "I know what features an 'advanced' camera should have, and this one is lacking in that regard".

Comment: Thank you, but the meaning of my sentence is a bit different. The speaker is confused why no proxy can open the filtering. It means most filterings are opened by a proxy, so it must be so advanced filtering that can't even be opened by a proxy. The speaker wonders which kind of filtering that is....

Comment: For another example consider "I don't know which technology they used in this mobile set that even works under water". Is it a correct sentence. If yes what is the structure of it?

Comment: @Ahmad:  From ***even* works under water** the listener understands that the under-water feature is something that deserves our focused attention.  The word **even** is a kind of attention-getter that is used to point out a salient fact.  We gather from your first clause that this feature must be *novel*, since you are not familiar with it.

Comment: I think it would be more natural not to use a *that*-clause and to move **even** to the main clause:  **I can't even imagine what sort of filter this might be, since it can't be opened by a proxy**.   When **even** is in the subordinate clause it tends to suggest that a proxy has a special ability to open things.  *That must be some fantastic encryption algorithm since it can't even be cracked by the NSA's supercomputers.*

Comment: There is nothing wrong with: the kind of x that can't even be [past participle] by [noun].

Answer (score 0):

**Correct placement of a that clause**:

Incorrect placement:
I don't know which kind of filtering they used that can't even be opened by a proxy!

Correct placement:
 I don't know which kind of **filtering that can't even be opened by a proxy** they used!

Or

I don't which kind of filtering they used; it can't even be opened by a proxy

I don't know which kind of filtering they used, which can't even be opened by a proxy.

the that clause has to be attached to the antecedent (the noun or phrase) it is attached to. The **book that** was on the table was closed.

However, here, you might want two sentences, as your ***that*** clause is so long: 
I don't know which kind of filtering they used. It can't even be opened by a proxy.

THIS: a **that** has to immediately follow what it refers to. "**the kind of filtering that can't be opened by proxy**" is the phrase. Not: "**the kind of filtering they used that can't be opened by a proxy**".

Because then, this too would be acceptable:
- **the game they played that cannot be beat**.
- **the movie we saw that was so good**.

Those **should be**:
- **the game that cannot be beat that they played** 
- **the movie that was so good that we saw**.

Some people in speech do tack on verbs after the noun to which the **that** refers, but it can lead to confusion and should not be used in writing.

Correct placement of that clause when that is a relative pronoun:
**I don't know which technology they used in this mobile set **that even works under water**.

That can be used as a subordinate conjunction:

He knew that the card players were cheating. [notice the worlds **knew that**]

**As a subordinate conjunction**
The word “that” can be used as a subordinate conjunction, that is, as a word that marks the **beginning of a dependent clause**.

**As a relative pronoun** 
The word “that” can be used as a relative pronoun; in other words, as a pronoun that begins a subordinate clause and is the subject of that clause.   **A relative pronoun not only marks the beginning of a dependent clause, as a subordinate conjunction does, but also, unlike a subordinate conjunction,  acts as the subject of that dependent clause**."

Therefore:

**I don't know which technology they used in this mobile set **that even works under water**** is a correct sentence as **that** marks the beginning of the clause and **is its subject**.

[the many uses of **that**](https://magoosh.com/gmat/2013/gmat-sentence-correction-the-many-uses-of-that/)

Comment: Actually, rereading myself I think what I said is basically right. it will return to this to further clarify it tomorrow. No time now. Generally, that clauses have to follow what they are attached to. "that can't even be opened by proxy" has to be next to filtering. It's not my rule. It is the rule for that.

Comment: It's a bad rule, and you should bin it. (The order you mark as incorrect is commonly encountered and there's nothing wrong with it.) I wish you luck.

Comment: The order I mark as incorrect?? I think the only rule that makes sense is that a **that** has to immediately follow what it refers to. "filtering that can't be opened by proxy" is the phrase. Not: "filtering they used that can't be opened by a proxy".

Comment: Unless you provide a credible source for your claims, my downvote will remain in place. I believe your intentions are good, but labeling things as "(in)correct" for stylistic reasons is really pushing it. I'm sorry. I would explain how the order labeled as "incorrect" might be ambiguous or lead to confusion, but I would not, at any rate, go on to claim that it's ungrammatical.

Comment: Oh so, only I need a "source for my claims'"? Perhaps you did not notice that Tᴚoɯɐuo's examples are exactly the same as mine? His that clauses following directly after the noun they refer to.

Comment: The website you linked preaches nonsense. One factitious rule they prescribe, for example, is this one: "The word 'that' cannot refer to an action, such as blocking penalty kicks." If they had simply taken a look at [a dictionary entry for *that*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/that), they'd have seen the following definition: "Used to refer to the event, action, or time just mentioned." Unfortunately, your source isn't credible enough, so you'll have to find a better one (or give up while you can).

Comment: Please leave other answers/answerers out of this comment section; they're not claiming what you have posited here. If someone gives an example of something you consider "correct", that doesn't mean they agree with you on all (the other) points. I don't want to continue this discussion. Best of luck.

Comment: "The goalkeeper blocked two penalty kicks in the second  half of the game and that caused his team to win the game." is OK in **spoken language**. It is not OK in writing to have the **that** act as a demonstrative pronoun and subject introducing a dependent clause after the word "and". "He tried to explain the movie and that got him into trouble." Fine for literature and speaking. Not fine for an article in ***Sports' Illustrated***.

Comment: There is no rule against referring to other answers that show what I'm showing. You are welcome to downvote. That's fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my other answer I was guessing at what you were trying to say, since the meaning of the filters and proxies example wasn't apparent to me.  I guessed wrong. But now that you have cleared this up with your comments, here's a second go at an answer.

You're trying to express the idea

This filter is strange or novel. It cannot be opened by a proxy, but most filters *can* be opened by a proxy.

Your first statement is therefore OK:

> I don't know which kind of filtering they used that can't even be opened by a proxy!

but your second is unidiomatic and ungrammatical:

> I don't know which kind of filtering they used that even it can't be opened by a proxy!

You're using **even** unidiomatically there, for one thing, placing emphasis on  the filter when your meaning requires emphasis on a proxy's usual ability to open filters. But let's set that issue aside and focus on the ungrammatical.

The pattern of your desired sentence can be paraphrased as follows:

How can this be a *normal* or *typical* {x} when {y} is true?

or

I don't know what sort of {x} this is when {y} is true.

**How can this be a normal filter when a proxy cannot open it?**

If you use **that** instead of **when** to introduce your subordinate clause, it is ungrammatical to repeat a reference to the {x} in the  relative clause as you do

...**filtering**...that even **it**...

The noun **filtering** is the antecedent of pronoun **it** in the relative clause.  That is a no-no:

> How can this be a normal or typical filter that it cannot be opened by a proxy? <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

But a reference to  {x} of the main clause can be placed in the relative clause if you  use **when** to introduce the relative clause:

> How can this be a normal or typical filter when it cannot be opened by a proxy? <sup>grammatical</sup>